# Posting form without @HTML.Beginform and using Jquery(ajax) in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

How can I fill out a form without using @HTML.Beginform and by using JQuery Ajax instead? Right now I tried:

```
    var postData = { form1: username, form2: password };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Controller/Method',
        data: postData,
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true
    });
```

But after posting, the browser does not navigate to the correct view. Of course I have return View() correctly in controller. Using Fiddler I see that it's correctly posted and the response is correct too...

Do I **have** to use @HTML.Beginform or can I do it with Ajax?

Comment: Where are you handling the response?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your can use either a raw HTML `<form>` tag or the `@HTML.BeginForm` helper. Here is an example using just `HTML`

## Complete solution:

```
<form action"/Controller/Method" method="POST" id="signInForm">
    <input type="text" name="form1" />
    <input type="text" name="form2" />
    <input type="submit" value="Sign in" />
</form>

$( function() {
    $( 'signInForm' ).submit( function( evt ) {
        //prevent the browsers default function
        evt.preventDefault();
        //grab the form and wrap it with jQuery
        var $form = $( this );
        //if client side validation fails, don't do anything
        if( !$form.valid() ) return;
        //send your ajax request
        $.ajax( {
            type: $form.prop( 'method' ),
            url: $form.prop( 'action' ),
            data: $form.serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            success: function( response ) {
                document.body.innerHTML = response;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I recommend using `@Url.Action` to set the URL of your form action. This way routing can generate your URL.

```
<form action"@Url.Action("Method", "Controller")" method="POST" id="signInForm">
    <input type="text" name="form1" />
    <input type="text" name="form2" />
    <input type="submit" value="Sign in" />
</form>
```

It is slightly more advanced, but I would try using something like [Take Command](http://www.nuget.org/packages/TakeCommand.js/) to manage your jQuery Ajax calls.

Disclaimer, I am a contributor to the TakeCommand project.

Comment: Thank you but this isn't the complete solution. What does the server side method look like? I run this but I continue to receive null data on the server side. :/

Comment: @Dermot In this case, the server action would look something like this: `public ActionResult Method(string form1, string form2)`

Comment: Hmm, that's what I had but it still wasn't working. I'll try it with a fresh head tomorrow and if I can't get it working will post a new question. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: The correct action code: action="@Url.Action("Method", "Controller")"

Answer (score 2):

When you're using `@Html.BeginForm`, the HTML output is:

```
<form method="POST" action="/Controller/Method">
```

And when you submit that form, the browser handles it just like another page navigation (only using `POST` method) hence the response is loaded into the parent frame.

But, when you're initiating an `Ajax` request, it's up to you to handle the response from the server (typically using a callback function).

If you want to simulate the regular form submission behavior, it would be something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Controller/Method',
    data: postData,
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,
    success: function(response)
    {
        document.body.innerHTML = response;
    }
});
```

This would not replace the entire page content with the response (only the `BODY` contents) but in most cases it will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This will do a xhr post to the server and return the view as data (response)
It will not navigate, if it returns html, you need to set a proper datatype in your request to tell that you expect html back from the server:

Given your action returns html, you can put the returned html on your page in your success function.

```
postData = "{'ID':'test'}";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Home/Test',
    data: postData,
    dataType: 'html',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    traditional: true,
    success: function (data) {
        $("#yourdomelement").html(data);
    }
});
```

In your action;

```
public ActionResult Test([FromBody]PostData id)
{
    return Content("<p>hello</p>");
}
```